# Returning loop of javascript http requests with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, bluebird, cheerio

I have a function which is looping through an array of urls to be parsed through [requests](https://github.com/request/request). Because however, I need the for loop to be encompassing the request I don't know how I can return the array. If I have the return of promises outside of the request, I lose the pushed elements since requests is a function. I'm using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for the promises.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function getSrc (urls, fileList) {
    var path = "#section > a[href]";
    var container = [];
    var i = 0;

    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
        for (; i < urls.length; i++ ) {         
            request(urls[i], function (err, resp, page) {
                if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                    var $ = cheerio.load(page); // load the page
                    fileList.push($(path).attr("src"));
                    container.push(fileList);
                    fullfill(container);
                } // end error and status code
                else {reject('error');}
            }); // end request    
        } // end FOR loop
        // fullfill(container); // how can i get this to wait for requests to fill array?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a for-loop in this way because all of your requests will run at the same time and the first to complete will call your `fullfill`(sic) callback.

The accepted way to accomplish this would be to use `Promise.map()` to iterate over your urls. Something like:

```
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));

Promise.map(urls,request.get).catch(function(err){
    // oops, one of the requests failed!
  }).then(function(results){
    // do something with the array of all results, one for each url.
  });
```